# How do I get the heart to stay in a fixed position when resizing webpage

Tags: html, css

I have created a heart using CSS pseudo-elements (found this code on google) and I want to fix it on the top right of my image but it moves when changing the webpage size.

I have tried using position: fixed; but when I do this the heart disappears completely.

CSS of heart:

[See picture of where i want the heart to stay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTFoY.png)

```
.heart {
background-color: rgb(0, 255, 229);
display: inline-block;
height: 30px;
margin: 0 10px;
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
right: 250px;
width: 30px;
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
content: "";
background-color: rgb(0, 255, 229);
border-radius: 50%;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
width: 30px;
}

.heart:before {
top: -15px;
left: 0;
}

.heart:after {
left: 15px;
top: 0;
}
```

HTML of heart:

```
<span class="heart"></span>
```

CSS of image:

```
.katieimg {
border-radius: 10px;
border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 50%;
max-width: 200px;
max-height: 250px;
}
```

HTML of image:

```
<img class="katieimg" src="images/me.jpeg" />
```

Comment: If you want it to always be relative to your picture, then instead of using absolute position; do relative

Comment: You'll need to position it in relation to the image of the person. Please could you provide slightly more complete code that includes that image.

Comment: @AHaworth Hi, Thank you for your comment. I have edited the post with the code of the image

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the heart absolute as you have done but relative to the image, not to the viewport or body.

This snippet therefore changes the HTML so the img is within a div and the heart code is within the same div.

The div picks up its height depending on the width it's been set so the img stays the right aspect ratio.

The heart is placed at the right and top of the div. You will want to play with the placing of the heart to get it exactly where you want it in terms of the parent div.

You may also want to change its sizing from being based on px units to relative to its parent's width, so that it gets smaller as the viewport gets smaller.

```css
.heart {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 229);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 229);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
}

.heart:before {
  top: -15px;
  left: 0;
}

.heart:after {
  left: 15px;
  top: 0;
}

.person {
  width: 50vw;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
}

.person img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="person"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300"><span class="heart"></span></div>
```